# "Unfortunately the process com.android.phone has stopped" after upgrade to Lollipop on my S5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I upgraded (over the air) to Lollipop and now the phone process keeps crashing. I tried to wipe its data (actually, in Application manager there are 3 'Phone' apps), tried turning off (including taking out the battery), tried deleting the cache.

Is there something more I can do except reset?

Comment: This kind of behavior appears whenever I upgrade or downgrade to a certain Android version. All I do after OTA/flashing is Boot into Recovery, clear the Cache and the Dalvik/Art Cache. That's it. It works usually. I don't know about lollipop though. Worked for Jellybean-Kitkat and Kitkat-Kitkat. If you ever find the reason for such beheviour, do post it here.

Comment: how do i delete the dalvik cache (my phone is not rooted)?

Comment: Boot into Recovery, depending upon your model there must be some `power+Vol Up` type of key combination to boot into Recovery. Once you're there, you will see the option to clear Cache as well as Dalvik/Art cache.

Comment: There is no option for Dalvik cache in my recovery (the stock one)

Comment: Then go ahead with the simple cache.

Comment: Supposedly L is no longer using *Dalvik*, but *Art*, so just try it or run the upgrade again.

Comment: how do i run an upgrade again?

Comment: @IttayD you can reinstall it by using your computer.

Comment: I had the same problem when I updated on 2015-04-09. I also had three "phone" apps in Application manager and an error was appearing every minute. Stopping phone app did not help, erasing the cache did not help. But I was able to do a backup and then factory reset (Settings -> Backup -> Factory reset). Then I restored from backup and I had to manually put all the programs on the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall Lollipop by installing [ODIN](http://odindownload.com/downloads/Odin-V3.10.6.exe) onto your computer.

and then you download lollipop, that is compatible with odin, for your S5 [HERE](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/).

Your model number for your S5 on the phone underneath the battery. You search that on the website.

**These are the steps you do next**

1. Turn off phone.
2. Hold the Volume Down Button, Home button, and Power button.
3. Ignore the warning message and press the volume up button to continue.
4. Connect Phone to Computer
5. Allow computer to install drivers.
6. Extract the ZIP file of Lollipop into the ODIN FOLDER.
7. Open ODIN
8. Click on the PDA button.
9. Select the extracted *tar.md5 file.
10. Click Start!
11. You should be running Lollipop before you know it!

Comment: I tried this already. Didn't solve my issue.